# Django Rest Framework Routing 2 things with regex

Tags: regex, django, rest, django-rest-framework, url-routing

I'm setting up an API Endpoint using Django Rest Framework viewsets and routers, and I'm trying to get the url to accept two values: first, to filter objects by a `user_id`, and then by the object's id. (In my case, the objects are from a model called `Request`.) For example, `mysite.com/api/requests/1A/` would return all `Request` objects for `user 1A`, and `mysite.com/api/requests/1A/23/` would return `Request` object with `pk=23` for `user 1A`.

Right in my `urls.py`:

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'requests/(?P<user_id>.+?)(?=\/)', viewset=views.RequestsByUser, base_name='request')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]

# views.py

class RequestsByUser(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = RequestsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        u_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
        return Request.objects.filter(user_id=u_id)
```

This works well for listing all `Request` objects when the url is only passed the `user_id`. But when I try to also pass the object's id example: `mysite.com/api/requests/1A/23/`, rest framework returns an empty result.

So the url will properly filter by `user_id`, but won't properly serve the detailed view of an object when given its primary key (`object_id`). (It looks like the proper page for a detailed view, except it's missing the data for the object.)

Django debugging says that the following four url patterns are in my URLConf:

```
^api/ ^ ^test/(?P<user_id>.+?)(?=\/)/$ [name='request-list']
^api/ ^ ^test/(?P<user_id>.+?)(?=\/)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='request-list']
^api/ ^ ^test/(?P<user_id>.+?)(?=\/)/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='request-detail']
^api/ ^ ^test/(?P<user_id>.+?)(?=\/)/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='request-detail']
```

I've read through the Django Rest Framework docs for url routing several times, and I feel like I must be missing something. My understanding is the router will automatically create url routing for detailed views based on primary keys, and it looks like it's doing that in the URL Conf. Is my regular expression configured wrong, or maybe something else?

Comment: Why don't you use `query_param`. By that `django-rest-framework` has ready `SearchFilter, Filter` class for your problem already

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'rest_framework',
'django_filters',
...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
```

}

serializers.py

```
import django_filters.rest_framework


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'MyField', 'MyFavoriteField','OtherField')

class MyModelListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'MyField','MyFavoriteField',)
```

urls.py:

```
path('service_name/', MyModelListView.as_view(), name="something_name"),
```

GET:
    http://localhost:8070/services/service_name/?id=123&MyField=My%20Field%20Value

More Info:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering

Comment: Your answer is not focusing on *router.register* that's why we are not voting for it